# SQL Server Management Studio server roles

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I dont know if im doing something completely wrong or im just missing the point of SQL Server security.

Here's what I'm trying to do using SSMS, a simple two-level access (`network\DomainUsers`, `network\SQLAdmins`).

- Domain users would not be unable to view any tables within SSMS but can access data via applications.
- SQLAdmins see all

To start with I thought I had it cracked by setting up a new server role for domain users and assigning view and database/definition permisions then removing these from the public role - no joy!

Staying with the same settings I then branches down to the table to grant permissions but again no joy.

I've setup several roles / users and applied all forms of permissions but as soon as database/definition is altered in public it overrides everything. I thought public was a default setting which then became redundant when other roles became active?

Can someone please point me in the correct direction before either my head pops or the machine learns to fly :-)

- SSMS: v17.8.1
- SQL Server: 2012

Comment: First of all, Management Studio is a client application like any other. You can't meaningfully distinguish between accounts doing something in Management Studio vs. doing them in anything else. If the "applications" use specific ways of accessing the data like stored procedures, you can make a distinction there, but you would of course still be able to call those in Management Studio as well. Second, you should basically never mess with the permissions of the `public` role, lest you break stuff left, right and center. Use domain groups and database roles. For admins you only need `sysadmin`.

Comment: Hi Jeroen, public is the default for all users so to prevent users seeing tables i remove the view database/definition within public. SO by then granting these permissions within another custom server role I would have thought it would of over ruled public and given permission :- am i wrong with that thought?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you actually defined your roles (which isn't clear from your question) it can simply be that you DENY view any database on the public role. This will in turn make it so everyone is denied. Because everyone is always a part of the public role. (This is why messing with the public role is a bad idea).

Deny's trump Grants. So no matter what you grant them later on, the deny overrides it. So if you denied it at the top level, it will stay like that no matter what you specify later on.

The exception to this is, that you can always see the objects that you own. And members of the sysadmin server role can't be denied since they always jump in as the owner. So you can technically hide all databases by revoking view permissions on the public database. But then you need to make a shared login and assign ownership to the databases that you want to be viewable.

Of note is that in this case, it means they can do whatever they want in said databases. Since you can't 'deny' them rights in something they own (which is why they can view it in the first place).

In overall, you're better off finetuning roles on the DB level, or making some custom server roles depending on what you want to accomplish.

Note, unless you messed with the public role. Logins with no user mapping in a database can't see the tables within a database, they can only see the existance of the database itself.

Comment: Thanks Kramer, I was looking at it wrong. I thought public settings would then be overruled by a custom rule. All sorted now.